# Declare a base class method that can take arbitrary type of parameters in the Child

Tags: c#, initialization

In C#...

I'm designing a base class (can NOT use constructors for this), and I want to force any inheriting classes to implement a method to initialize their respective objects.  I can expect that their initialization method may take an **arbitrary** number and type of parameters.

how would I declare this abstract method in the base, so that the children can implement any parametered variation of it? If it is not possible, could you suggest an alternative? Thank you.

updated details : the base class should be abstract, i need a method to act as a constructor (but I can't use a constructor to do it). The child class needs a way to initialize itself, and I was hoping to force an implementation with an (abstract?) method of my own

Comment: are derived classes required to implement one and only one of this methods?

Comment: ideally yes, if it turns out better that there is no restriction of amount then no ;-)

Comment: Why do you want this? Who will call that method? Only the object implementing it or do you want your baseclass to call it from it's constructor? If only the implementing object is calling it it is odd to enforce from a base class that some method with a name exists (that won't guarantee it has been executed). If you want to call it from the baseclass that baseclass needs a predefined method with parameters it is aware of (or an object[]). Adding the 'what issue are your trying to solve' might help in getting good answers

Comment: the base class should be abstract, i need a method to act as a constructor (but I can't use a constructor to do it).  The child class needs a way to initialize itself, and I was hoping to force an implementation with an (abstract?) method of my own.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible try this code in your base class

```
 public abstract void Test(params object[] list);
```

now it will force to declare method in child class.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, that is a workable alternative. I was hoping for something that wouldn't force the child class cast the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can use [new Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to hide explicitly the same name methods, fields, ... of derived class

.NET framework 4.0 provide optional parameters and name arguments to deal with a various type of parameters [Named and Optional Arguements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)